# Asus X556U touch pad not working

Tags: suspend, touchpad, asus

After my laptop (Asus X556U) boots Ubuntu, the touchpad is not working.`xinput` command lists my touchpad as `Elan Touchpad`. I tried to enable & disable the touchpad, but still it is not working. But when I put the systdm in suspend mode and then log in again, the touchpad works fine.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I have nvidia 920m on this model and cant suspend with nvidia drivers, but my touchpad sometimes not work. i have USB mouse that work....

Comment: so, i opend a bug on this similar issue [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1646622](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1646622) and you can see there that in the next kernel there is fix for my problem, maybe you can try it.